# How can I view the function definition of the less than operator in c++

Tags: c++, function, definition

In c++98 the function header of the less than operator seems to be

```
template <class T> struct less : binary_function <T,T,bool> {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x<y;}
}
```

Where can I view the function definition for the less than operator? All references I find online explain the function in detail, but don't provide the actual definition.

In class I'm currently overloading the less than operator to work with my own objects, and while my code is complete, it seems overly complicated. I hoped the original less than might provide some insight on a simpler method.

Comment: What do you mean by "the original less than operator"? base types (like int and float) have one but you wont find that definition anywhere, the compiler just "knows about it", any user data type has to provide its own.

Comment: If I'm overloading a function (the less than operator), there has to be an original function to be overloaded, no?

Comment: There's no "original" operator to look at. It's built in for primitives, and `less` uses the appropriate overload for the type `T` that it's instantiated with.

Comment: @UriahWardlaw Youre confusing overloading (same name different parameters) with overriding (same signature, name + params, but in a derived class, this only applies in cases of inheritance)

Comment: That makes sense. Perhaps a better question would be, where can I view the template definition?

Comment: Template definition of what?

Comment: @UriahWardlaw There's no template definition either. You're searching for something that doesn't exist except on a conceptual level. Why don't you post your overly complicated definition and ask what to do about it?

Comment: If `less` is a template, and mlbdnilo is saying `less`implements an understanding of how less than works with primitive types, `less` must still have a definition where the template is defined.

Comment: @molbdnilo where can I do that?

Comment: @UriahWardlaw the definition of `less` is what you posted. The `<` operator is what's built in for primitives and overloaded for user defined types. You can probably find those definitions by looking for the source of the user defined types. What more are you looking for?

Comment: I would hate to have to include a header file just to compare numbers.

Comment: @UriahWardlaw That's not what I said at all. An instantiation of `less` for a specific type `T` *uses* the `<` operator, which is built in for primitive `T` and may be overloaded for other types `T`. It knows nothing about what `<` means, has no idea about whether it's overloaded or not, and it's not a definition of `<` in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In c++98 the function header of the less than operator seems to be ...

It seems that you've shown a definition of `std::less`. It is a templated function object that compares two objects.

> Where can I view the function definition for the less than operator?

That depends on the type argument that was used to instantiate the `std::less` template. If `T` is a fundamental type, then less than operator is not a function at all, but a built-in operator. As such, there is no function definition.

If `T` is a user defined type (a class), then the less than operator resolves to an operator overload, which is a function. As with all definitions of a function, you can find them in the source code. Regexp `operator\s<` might be of use.